# Why if you down one of the interfaces(active) used in a bond(active-backup mode) the connection to the server is lost?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, bonding, oracle-linux

Tried to configure bonding on Oracle8.7
The only problem is, trying to test it out if it works fine or not, found a little problem
when you shutdown active interfaces used in the bond the connection to the server is lost. It does show that the secondary interface turns active, but thats it.. you can't ping the server.. you cant ping anything from it.. nothing..
But if you physically unplug the cable of an active interface - it functions just fine, switching to the secondary interface, pings the server with a little delay and all, but works.
I thought its due to the switch missconfigurations until I've tried to test it out on the VM. Using both manual configuration and using nmcli - result is just the same. And it did acted the same as with baremetal. So either its OS's faulth or maybe I am missing some configurations, os is it normal?
The opts I used for the bond are "mode=active-backup,miimon=100,primary=ens0"
Please help